# Case Insensitive Localization in iOS

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

While implementing localization I realize that localization is case sensitive, what means:

```
 - "Cookie Selection" = "Sélection de biscuit";

 - "COOKIE SELECTION" = "SÉLECTION DE BISCUIT";
```

above two are different entities. If you localize like  `NSLocalizedString("cookie selection", comment: "")`, this will not get localized as the key value mapping given for "cookie selection" is either for capitalized string or for Uppercased string.

Query: 
If I can make it case insensitive, in the sense like I will add only one pair for localization  as

```
"Cookie Selection" = "Sélection de biscuit";
```

and this should work for all cases like below

```
 1. NSLocalizedString("Cookie Selection", comment: "")
 2. NSLocalizedString("COOKIE SELECTION", comment: "")
 3. NSLocalizedString("cookie selection", comment: "")
```

**Note:** -> without any custom method, use only NSLocalization.

**Happy Coding**

Comment: How about `NSLocalizedString("Cookie Selection".lowercased(), comment: "")`?

Comment: What about keeping only `Cookie Selection` and then when you do `NSLocalizedString("Cookie Selection", comment: "")`, apply `.uppercased()` / `lowercased()` / `.capitalized` according to the case?

Comment: the keys in the localised-string file always take the case into account – but you could define your own naming conventions for the keys to keep it consistent, like e.g. using `lowercase_slugs`, `camelCase`, or `dot.notation` keys deliberately.

Comment: problem is when you are localizing dynamic data and you dont know in which case you are going to get it.

Comment: It should be case sensitive. You want it to be case sensitive. Don't make any attempt to avoid it being case sensitive. You may actually have the need to show the same text with different capitalization. And different localizations may result in different capitalizations.

Answer (score 2):

Nope....Better use a constant file where you will store all the localization constants and its values so by mistake localization constant value does not change by mistake(suppose you type **cookie Selection** instead of **Cookie Selection**)  while calling. You will use then values in localizable files as key.

**LocalizationConstants.swift**

```
let CookieSelectionKey = "Cookie Selection"
```

**Localizable.strings(English)**

```
"Cookie Selection" = "Selection Of cookie";
```

Now call it like

```
  NSLocalizedString(CookieSelectionKey, comment: "")
```

Since it returns a string you can use string instance methods such as **uppercased, capitalized(etc.)** to change case accordingly.

Comment: I agree with your solution and appreciate quick response. but the question is if "cookie selection" is the dynamic data that we are getting from server. then it will cause problem.

Comment: Anyhow you won't be creating  the localization file after url call. You and server will have to agree on the keys. If server changes the case while sending, you use the key as all capital and while  creating the localised string use the all capital version of key sent by server.

Comment: that is the issue @keshav. case is mismatching and we are forced to add duplicate vals.

Comment: Read the comment above. One approach might be use all the keys as case small or uppercased. Now when you get the key from server, either capitalise it or lowercase it before using it as key to create the localised string. So now there won't be the problem of case mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

You could always remove the possibility of getting it wrong by making a struct to encapsulate your localised logic etc...

```
enum Strings: String {
    case cookieSelection

    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, comment: "Something here")
    }
}
```

With something like this you can now keep track of all your localised strings in one place and also remove any chance of them being used incorrectly.

For usage do something like...

```
label.text = Strings.cookieSelection.localized
```

If you want a default value for the string you can add that to the case...

```
enum Strings: String {
    case cookieSelection = "Cookie Selection"
}
```

Comment: this will horrible if you application is already using NSLocalizedString and you come up with this solution. I found it at many places but dont really want to use. that is I added last line in my question that no custom method

Comment: @RishiChaurasia How will it be horrible? Please explain... according to me both will work.. NSLoacalizedString and someString.localized.

Comment: I agreed that this will work. I dont want to mess up with live app with multiple NSLocalized calls to replace. @KeshavRaj if go thru for NSlocalizations solutions you will get these solutions in first 3 links at max.

Comment: @RishiChaurasia I agree it will be a lot of work if you have a big project that needs updating. But this can be done bit by bit. Doing that work will then lead to the system in place and fewer problems with more strings. Always better to fix tech debt early rather than later. 

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most raw solution would be to always capitalize the key like so:

```
NSLocalizedString("cookie selection".uppercased(), comment: "Comment")
```

More cleaner approach would be to create a category on String class and use that method instead:

```
        extension String {
        public static func LocalizedString(key: String, comment: String) -> String {
            return NSLocalizedString(key.uppercased(), comment: comment)
        }
    }

// Usage

    String.LocalizedString(key: "cookie selection", comment: "")
```

Another nice approach would be to make a file of constants and use them instead of using hard coded strings.